# Iterate over group by in SQL Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Starting with the end goal, I want a result set looking like the following:

```
name  | completed
_________________
Josh  |  T
Tom   |  T
Harry |  F
```

I have a table that looks like:

```
id | name | status
__________________
1    Josh   complete
2    Josh   errored
3    Tom    generating
4    Tom    complete
5    Harry  pending
```

As you can see from the result set, I want to know for each person whether they have ever had a status of complete.
I think I want to iterate over each row in the grouped by clause checking `status = 'complete'` but I am struggling to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`bool_or` aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT name, bool_or(status = 'complete')
FROM test
GROUP BY name
```

yields

```
| name  | bool_or |
|-------+---------|
| Tom   | t       |
| Josh  | t       |
| Harry | f       |
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can do aggregation :

```
select name, coalesce(max(case when status = 'complete' then T end), 'F') as completed
from table t
group by name;
```

Comment: Thanks - Just so I understand, why are we using `max` here?

Comment: @JoshHale. . .  `max()` will give you `T` value if `status = 'complete'` found else it will return `null` as this is aggregated query so, will require aggregation function if column (`status`) not present with `group by` clause.

Comment: OK that makes sense. Thanks